# When I minus a “double” and a another “double” from an arrary, "class member declaration expected"

Tags: c#

Thank you for helping me!
I made two array which contains a few double numbers. I then made a function to randomly get a double out of an array. When I try to subtract a double and the double I extracted from two arrays, mistake happens in the last three lines——

> class member declaration expected.

How should I alter my code to avoid this problem?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{   

    double[] x =new Double[] { 30,35,40,45,55 };
    double[] y =new Double[] { 700,750,800,850,900 };

    double a;
    double b;
    double distance;

    public string GetRandom(arr)
   {   
　　　　Random ran = new Random();
　　　　int n = ran.Next(arr.Length - 1);
　　　　return arr[n];
　　}

      distance = GetRandom(y)
      a = a - distance;
      b.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty,a-GetRandom(x));
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can't run procedural code outside of a method.

Comment: `b` is `double` type. It does not have method `SetValue`

Comment: `distance = GetRandom(y)` is missing a closing `;`

Comment: Please make sure to post code that compiles. The GetRandom method is not correct

Comment: Statements have to be in a method or something similar. They can't just be in a `class`. When are you expecting these statements to run? Just once when you run the program? Or as part of the `GetRandom` method?

Comment: That is very PASCAL like.  Haven't seen this in a while...

Comment: You may want to consult the documentation on the use of `Random`.  Using it that way, it will eventually not work properly

Comment: Thank you guys! I'm not quite familiar with C#, which leads me to asking stupid question! But now I get to know what I should do! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You (generally)** can't execute code like that outside of a method.  Put those last three lines inside a method.

** In many cases you can assign a value to a class member field, which is basically syntactic sugar for doing the assignment in the class constructor.